# Dev Environment Extremely Slow When Resolving Domain

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn Laravel today and installed it with **composer** using the instructions in the [quick start guide](http://laravel.com/docs/quick). Everything went smooth, but when loading the default page, it took over 20 seconds. I figured it must be doing some setup and caching things so I went ahead and built a controller for testing like this:

```
class AuthorsController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('authors.index');
    }
}
```

Then I added "This is my view" to a file at **views/authors/index.php**.

Finally, I added this route:

```
Route::controller('authors', 'AuthorsController');
```

Going to `laravel.dev/authors` took 35.07 seconds to load 451 bytes (according to Google Chrome's inspector). Refreshing the page is roughly the same.

I am using Apache 2.2.4, PHP 5.3, on OSX 10.8. My **vhost** config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jeremyharris/Sites/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    <Directory "/Users/jeremyharris/Sites/laravel/public">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my **hosts** file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost laravel.dev
```

I've used this same style setup over and over again with hundreds of sites and with different frameworks. Why am I having so much trouble with Laravel?

Comment: Well, I can say that's not typical Laravel. It's likely something related to configuration, but there's tons of possibilities. Have you tried Vagrant or a VM of some sort instead of using your Mac directly?

Comment: I can't seem to get Vagrant to work as intended (even with PuPHPet). I always end up going in and installing a bunch of crap because writing *recipes* makes me want to stab my eyes out. I understand this isn't the fault of Laravel, please don't take it as an accusation.

Comment: I skip chef/puppet as well. If you spin up an Ubuntu instance, you can run [this shell script to install a LAMP stack](https://gist.github.com/fideloper/7074502) after SSHing into the Ubuntu box. That should work (does for me!)

Comment: @fideloper I will give that a try. Any suggestions on what to check configuration wise for my current setup?

Comment: Not really...could be file-system related, could be file permission related, could be the install of PHP and things like php5-mcrypt missing or misconfigured, could be mysql related. I mean... have you turned it off and on again? (seriously... :D )

Comment: have you tried serving using the built-in server? php artisan serve

Comment: Are you running PHP as CGI or Apache module?

Comment: @matpop As Apache module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and as I expected, it wasn't Laravel, it was something else. I said above that my hosts file had:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost laravel.dev
```

Which was a generalization because I have dozens of *.dev domains listed for various projects. In double checking my /etc/hosts file, I ended up putting **laravel.dev** before the localhost part like:

127.0.0.1   laravel.dev localhost

Apparently Apache looses all ability to resolve a domain when this happens. Switching it fixed the issue.

I will leave this here in case someone else has a similar issue but will change the title to be more descriptive.